# What is the meaning of Microsoft Compatibility Level?

Tags: sql-server, compatibility-level

Setting cmptlevel to 80 on a SQL-Server 2005 inhibits the use of PIVOT and APPLY, but doesn't affect the use of Analytical Functions. Is there any rational behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some rationale I've observed, but this isn't exhaustive and is my guesswork

Compatibility Level isn't an all-or-nothing thing. It provides partial backwards compatibility while you fix issues.

A trival example with LOCK hints

```
FROM
   Table (NOLOCK)   -- not allowed with level 90+
```

and

```
FROM
   Table WITH (NOLOCK)   -- WITH is optional for level 80
```

Why this is now mandatory, I don't know. To do with CTEs?

For PIVOT and APPLY I suspect that a SQL statement using these is simply illegal SQL Server 2000 syntax whereas ROW_NUMBER is just an unknown function and "less" critical

An example using CROSS APPLY. For 80 this is illegal SQL Server 2000 syntax.

```
FROM
   SomeTable S
   CROSS APPLY --or JOIN
   dbo.someTVF (S.column)
```

There are [many questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sp_dbcmptlevel) about errors because of lower levels in newer versions for you to review and hopefully get an understanding

FYI, [full list of 80-90 and 90-100 differences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx)

Comment: FROM table (NOLOCK) is supported in 90 (2005) and 100 (2008)

Comment: @samyi: kinda true, but see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms143179(SQL.90).aspx  Look for "WITH keyword when you are using table hints". And for SQL Server 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms143729(SQL.100).aspx

Answer (score 5):

[MSDN ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) explains the behavior of the various levels. (just scroll down and you will find the comparison tables for the following topics )

you can find more specific comparison tables if you just change the Version from MSDN top menu (they are linked for top 3 versions in following list)

- 80 = SQL Server 2000
- 90 = SQL Server 2005
- 100 = SQL Server 2008 and [R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680(v=sql.105).aspx)
- 110 = [SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680(v=sql.110).aspx)
- 120 = [SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680(v=sql.120).aspx)
- Differences Between Lower Compatibility Levels and Level 120

  - sample line (The older query optimizer is used instead of new SQL Server 2014 engine which includes substantial improvements to the component that creates and optimized query plans )
- Differences Between Lower Compatibility Levels and Level 110